# Cmake fails while configuring OpenCV

Tags: compiling, c++, c, cmake

I'm trying to buid OpenCV and use it in Qt. I have installed all required packages for OpenCV and Qt, after that I tried too run `cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local /media/d/Install/opencv-2.4.8` but I got errors:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:189 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:56 (project)


-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:185 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:56 (project)


-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:186 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:56 (project)


-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:71 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:56 (project)


-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:78 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:56 (project)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:70 (message):
  CMake fails to deterimine the bitness of target platform.

    Please check your CMake and compiler installation. If you are crosscompiling then ensure that your CMake toolchain file correctly sets the compiler details.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

CMakeLists.txt:56 :

```
project(OpenCV CXX C)
```

/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:189 :

```
configure_file(${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/CMakeSystem.cmake.in
                ${CMAKE_PLATFORM_INFO_DIR}/CMakeSystem.cmake
                IMMEDIATE @ONLY)
```

Comment: Are you executing `cmake` from a build directory also on `/media`? If so, I _suspect_ the problem is that it is on a filesystem such as NTFS that doesn't support Unix-style permission bits (or is mounted `noexec`). The compiler/ABI tests are likely trying to create and test minimal executables e.g. `./CMakeFiles/CompilerIdCXX/a.out` or `./CMakeFiles/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_C.bin` and are failing if those don't execute.

Comment: @steeldriver I moved opencv directory to the ext4 partition, now it seems to be compiling correctly. `make` still in process, but I think everything will be fine. 
I used to build opencv from ntfs partition on another computer, so I did not even think that the filesystem can cause such problems

Comment: I have the same problem in WSL, moving source files from NTFS to ext4 solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by removing the build folder in which I had previously started cmake but cancelled it during installation.
Now it works.